# Can't import .ova to VirtualBox and can't uncompress with `tar`

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, tar, ovf, ova

Having a problem with a ova file that is supposed to contain a VM image.

Importing into VirtualBox gives the error:

```
OVA 'path/to/filename.ova' does not contain an .ovf-file.

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: ApplianceWrap
Interface: IAppliance {86a98347-7619-41aa-aece-b21ac5c1a7e6}
```

Using tar to extract the ovf also does not work:

```bash
$ tar -xvf filename.ova
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It all looks as though the file format is incorrect, but it has been imported successfully by others on my course so it seems unlikely.

I am unsure how to further troubleshoot this issue and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: Hi @Rob. Thank you for pointing this out. In future I will consider this point much more carefully.

The third point on the page you linked reads "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". It's true that my question was too general, but - VMs are tools used all the time for software development, and indeed that is why I was using one.

I already received a valid response to my issue, so it seems unnecessary to remove now when others may find this page useful, or I'd be more inclined to remove.

Comment: Your question is up for closure because it's not about programming whatsoever so it won't help anyone at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the OVA has been truncated or is missing some portion.
Check the file size and checksum of the OVA file to ensure that it has not been corrupted during download or transfer.